# Filter array elements by searching for partial match in keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, regex, search, filtering

is it possible to do searching in PHP array same we do in MySQL.

Eg: I have this `array`

```
array(
  'mark@test.com'=> `Mark Mian`,
  'jhon@test.com'=> `John jack`,
  'logon@test.com'=> `Bob Logon`,
  'Stela@test.com'=> `Stela Josh`,
  'json@test.com'=> `Json Josh`
  'bobby@test.com'=> `Bob Mark`
)
```

and I would to do this type of searching,

**Eg: If I search `Mark` it should return me this**

> 'mark@test.com' => `Mark Mian

**If I search `Bob` it should return me**

> 'bobby@test.com'=> `Bob Mark`
>
> 'logon@test.com'=> `Bob Logon`,

**If I search only `a` it should return me those elements which contains `a` eg:**

> 'mark@test.com'=> `Mark Mian`,
>
> 'jhon@test.com'=> `John jack`,
>
> 'Stela@test.com'=> `Stela Josh`,
>
> 'bobby@test.com'=> `Bob Mark`

***Note: Search should be by key or value***

Comment: You can use **regex** or `str_pos` for this. But have you tried anything?

Comment: Try using [`preg_grep`](https://ideone.com/MNELWl)

Comment: ***Note: Search should be by or value*** That typo is confusing. Please consider fixing

Comment: @HankyPanky Fixed typo..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your answer is superb, Can you explain little more, that how we can do search in `array keys`

Comment: @Qazi `preg_grep` couldn't search in array keys - if you want to, you should use `preg_grep` on `array_keys($array)`

Comment: @Philipp Yes, you are right. your statement make sense. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please Place your answer, so I can mark as best solution

Comment: @HankyPanky You could combine `array_filter` and `preg_grep` to search for both at the same time ;)

Comment: If the question was asking about how to "emulate" *`WHERE col REGEXP 'PATTERN'`*, I'd post the `preg_grep` based solution, but HP's solution is enough for the `LIKE` case-insensitive literal string search.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you post this scenario too, It would be much appreciable.

Comment: @Qazi: Please check my answer. It is more a REGEXP "emulation", not LIKE construct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a `preg_grep` solution that should work more like a `WHERE REGEXP 'PATTERN'` in MySQL. I modified [Daniel Klein's `preg_grep_keys` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php#111673) to search for the pattern within array keys, and added an [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to it, which *should work with the arrays with non-numeric keys*. If the keys are numeric, just use a mere [`preg_grep` solution](https://ideone.com/MNELWl) (`preg_grep('~Mark~i', $arr);` to find all array elements having `mark` or `Mark`, etc.).

> [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
>   Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.
>   **If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one.** If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

```
function preg_grep_keys_values($pattern, $input, $flags = 0) {
    return array_merge(
      array_intersect_key($input, array_flip(preg_grep($pattern, array_keys($input), $flags))),
      preg_grep($pattern, $input, $flags)
   );
}

$a = array(
  'mark@test.by.com'=> "Mark Mian lv",
  'jhon@test.lv.com'=> "John jack lv",
  'logon@test.en.com'=> "Bob Logon",
  'Stela@test.es.com'=> "Stela Josh",
  'json@test.es.com'=> "Json Josh",
  'bobby@test.lv.com'=> "Bob Mark"
);

$r = preg_grep_keys_values('~lv~i', $a);
print_r($r);
```

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/WO1r4m)

The code above searches for `lv` (case-insensitively) in the keys first, then in the values, and then merges the results into 1 array. Thus, the results are:

```
[jhon@test.lv.com] => John jack lv
[bobby@test.lv.com] => Bob Mark
[mark@test.by.com] => Mark Mian lv
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$needle="bob";
$output=array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
   if(stristr($k,$needle) || stristr($v,$needle))
   $output[$k]=$v;
}
print_r($output);
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/538540)**

That is if you want to search keys and values both, Remove the *keys* part if you just want to search values.

Comment: I would have defined an empty `$output` initially.

Comment: @HankyPanky I will look into this, what you suggest about `array_filter()` function, Would it work ?

Answer (score 4):

An easy approach would be to use `array_filter`

If you want regex's, this would work

```
$regex = '~test~';
$result = array_filter($data, function($item) use ($regex) {
    return preg_match($regex, $item);
});
```

Or just a simple contains search

```
$search = 'test';
$result = array_filter($data, function($item) use ($search) {
    return stristr($value, $search);
});
```

If you have to search for both - key and value, you could append the parameter `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` to array_filter.

```
$search = 'test';
$result = array_filter($data, function($item, $key) use ($search) {
    return stristr($value, $search) || stristr($key, $search);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

And finally, you could combine array_filter with preg_grep to search for both at once.

```
$search = '~bob~i';
$result = array_filter($data, function() use ($search) {
    return count(preg_grep($search, func_get_args()));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Comment: Sorry one more. What about `'~bob~i';` :P. +1 regardless

Comment: @HankyPanky I added an preg_grep version which searched for both at the same time

Comment: using `stristr` is a bad idea, because 1) you don't need to extract the substring, 2) if the needle parameter can be evaluated to false, you will get a wrong result, example: `if (stristr('abc0abc', '0')) echo 'toto';`. You should use `stripos` instead and testing if it with a strict comparaison: `return stripos(.....) !== false;`

Answer (score 2):

You want to filter an array, use `array_filter` that is designed for.

If you only search literal strings, you don't need to use a regex:

```
$needle = 'bob';

$result = array_filter($data, function ($k, $v) use ($needle) {
    return stripos($k, $needle) !== false || stripos($v, $needle) !== false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

If you want to be able to filter with a regex:

```
$pattern = '~n.*e~i';

$result = array_filter($data, function ($k, $v) use ($pattern) {
    return !empty(preg_grep($pattern, [$k, $v]));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $search = "Mark"

  $array = array(
  'mark@test.com'=> `Mark Mian`,
 'jhon@test.com'=> `John jack`,
 'logon@test.com'=> `Bob Logon`,
 'Stela@test.com'=> `Stela Josh`,
 'json@test.com'=> `Json Josh`
'bobby@test.com'=> `Bob Mark`
 )
       foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
         if (stristr($value, $search) == '') {
        //not found
        }else{
      //found
       }
```

this is the best approach search for any substring , case-insensitive and fast

> just like like in mysql

ex:

> select  * from table where name = "%Mark%"

Answer (score 0):

From PHP8, `str_contain()` becomes the preferred native function to make case-sensitive searches with reduced syntax.

Searching for a lowercase `b` does a fine job of demonstrating the case-sensitive search on keys and values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uimRU))

```
$array = [
    'mark@test.by.com'=> "Mark Mian lv",
    'jhon@test.lv.com'=> "John jack lv",
    'logon@test.en.com'=> "Bob Logon",
    'Stela@test.es.com'=> "Stela Josh",
    'json@test.es.com'=> "Json Josh",
    'bobby@test.lv.com'=> "Bob Mark"
];

$needle = 'b';

var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn($v, $k) => str_contains($v, $needle) || str_contains($k, $needle),
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'mark@test.by.com' => 'Mark Mian lv',
  'logon@test.en.com' => 'Bob Logon',
  'bobby@test.lv.com' => 'Bob Mark',
)
```

If you want to be cute and make a single function call inside of `array_filter()`, then you could just concatenate `$v` and `$k` together, but then you risk the arbitrarily nominated delimiting character(s) being matched.  For stability, just make two calls per iteration.

---

Putting a modern spin on @Casimir's snippets:

(The `$k` and `$v` in the callback signatures of their answer are misleading/out-of-order.)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TUCpg))

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn($v, $k) => stripos($k, $needle) !== false || stripos($v, $needle) !== false,
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
    )
);
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UtAvA))

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn(...$both) => greg_grep($pattern, $both),
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_array = array_filter($data_array , function ($item) use ($your_string) {
            return strpos($item['array_key'], $your_string) !== false;
        });
```

This replace the array with matching string